# asp.net mvc - html value is not rendering properly in view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have html code in database. my model gets assign with correct data from database. but when displaying on page its not there.

my model:

```
public class myModel
{
   public string id {get; set;}
   public string data {get; set;}
}
```

my view :

```
<div id="tabs1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">firsttab</a></li>
  </ul>

   <div id="tabl">
      <p><%= Model.data%></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please note data is HTML data. and i am using JqueryUI widget TABS. here is data example:

```
   <DIV><B>Edited by USER NAME on Tuesday, January 31, 2012 at 12:11 PM</B><BR> </DIV>
```

when i try to run this code on my local machine it works fine. but when i deploy to server this data is not rendering.

any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you forget the @ before model, or is it not needed in .net mvc 2?

@Model.data, that is.

Comment: @DanielHqHallqvist this is MVC2 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Html.Raw()` in MVC3+:

```
<div id="tabl">
   <p><% Html.Raw(Model.data) %></p>
</div>
```

Use `MvcHtmlString.Create` in MVC2:

```
<div id="tabl">
   <p><%: MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.data) %></p>
</div>
```

Comment: i found it.. it was connection issue. thank you guys... it was helpfull information.

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

You have to use `Html.Raw` to output html.

> **Html.Raw** Returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

#### Sample

```
<%= Html.Raw(Model.data) %>
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - HtmlHelper.Raw Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)